# Converting URL into clickable link using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a text field called 'patentURL' in a form. The user enteres the complete URL into this field while saving the record. When the user searches for this record, the entered URL should be clickable. i.e. in the result page, the entered URL should be clickable.

How do I achieve this using Javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Javascript to get url of the page and use it in a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283399/use-javascript-to-get-url-of-the-page-and-use-it-in-a-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you should put the url in a link:

```
<a href = "URL_ENTERED">URL_ENTERED</a>
```

With javascript:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');//create link
link.setAttribute('href', 'URL_ENTERED');//set href
link.innerHTML = 'URL_ENTERED';//set text to be seen
document.body.appendChild(link);//add to body
```

Comment: How do I use this 'href' in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

There is a non-standard function, but widely spread - link() [<sup>MDC</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link)

```
function makeClickable(url) {
    return String.prototype.link ? url.link(url) : '<a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>';
}

function makeDOMClickable(url) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.innerHTML = url;
    return link;
}

var url = "http://localhost";
document.write ( makeClickable ( url ) );
document.body.appendChild ( makeDOMClickable ( url ) );
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6mYCf/)

Answer (score 1):

Example to call `href` in Javascript:

```
function call_link() {
    location.href = 'www.google.com';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript regular expression to achieve this have a look

```
function convert()
{
  var text=document.getElementById("url").value;
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  var text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
  var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
  document.getElementById("converted_url").innerHTML=text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
}
```

this way you can convert any text into link you can find more detail here http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/convert-url-text-into-clickable-html-links-using-javascript.php