# Use Javascript to get url of the page and use it in a link

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have looked and looked for an answer to this question. So I apologize in advance when the solution is very easy.

I want to take the url of the current page eg. www.example.com/example.html and put this in a link (among other uses) using javascript.

so it would look like this:

```
<a href"www.example.com/example.html"></a>
```

I've tried lots of things I know I need to use location.href but just can't seem to get it to work.

This is the closest I got to getting it to work,:

```
<a href"javascript:write.location.href;"></a>
```

Thanks, sorry again. I'm new to JS and html.

J

Comment: Offtopic, but if you just want to have a link that reloads the current page, you can use <a href="#"></a>.

Comment: thanks, yeah I want to pass the url on to something else though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your element with an ID, like: `<a id="pageLink"></a>` and then when the document loads you can run this snippet:

```
var link = document.getElementById("pageLink");
link.setAttribute("href", window.location.href);
```

Or, with something like jQuery:

```
$("#pageLink").attr("href", window.location.href);
```

**EDIT** In response to your question in the comments:

I'm not sure I'm understanding you completely but if it's fixed, then you'd simply concatenate to the href before setting it, e.g.

```
$("#pageLink").attr("href", staticUrl + window.location.href);
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I then concatenate this url with another url? eg. www.sendto.com/submit?url=id="www.example.com/example.html"

Comment: @jimmyp1399473 How are you getting this other URL? String concatenation in Javascript is simply `str1 + str2`

Comment: the other url would be fixed the same for all webpages

Answer (score 0):

you can use `document.location.href` to find the address of the current page

```
<a id="cool-link">click it!</a>
<script>
jQuery('#cool-link').attr('href', document.location.href)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `window.location.href`. I'm no JS expert, so let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.location.href=document.URL">same url link</a>
```

you can keep the href empty and just use the onclick event.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` in href (it's global object) but you can in onclick.

```
<a onclick="this.setAttribute('href', location);this.setAttribute('onclick', '');">foo</a>
```

It clear onclick so you get this only once so you can follow the link if you click it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function gotolink(){
    location.href = location.href;
}
</script>

<a href"#" onclick="gotolink();">Click here!</a>
```