# How can I make the link in the code below an href? I can't seem to make it a clickable link

Tags: javascript, html

```
user = "1401";
document.write("User|"+CallSINIMethod("GetValue", ["UserField", "UserProfileFirstName", user])+"|<br><br>");


docs = CallSINIMethod("GetListValue", ["UserListProperty", "OrderedDocuments", user]);

i = 0;

while (i < docs.length) {

    document.write(CallSINIMethod("GetValue", ["DocumentProperty", "ProductName", docs[i]])+"|"+docs[i]+"|<br>");
    document.write("http://goodsamstorefront.com/goodsamstorefront/GetProof.aspx?id="+docs[i]+"<br>");
    document.write(CallSINIMethod("GetValue", ["VariableValue", "__DateUpdatedInCart", docs[i]])+"<br>");
    document.write(CallSINIMethod("GetValue", ["VariableValue", "__DocumentStatus", docs[i]])+"<br>");
    document.write(CallSINIMethod("GetValue", ["DocumentProperty", "EditingStatus", docs[i]])+"<br><br/>");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping it in an <a> tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting URL into clickable link using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511900/converting-url-into-clickable-link-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Ryan, since this is within a javascript function that is also adding the docs[i] to the url, simply adding an <a href> tag will not do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To make the link clickable you should use the [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag. For example:

```
<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>
```

Is a link that both goes to Google and says "https://google.com"

Comment: Thanks J, since this is within a javascript function that is also adding the docs[i] to the url, simply adding an <a href> tag will not do the trick.

Comment: You could make it work by using a separate variable like:
`var url = "http://goodsamstorefront.com/goodsamstorefront/GetProof.aspx?id="+docs[i];`
`document.write("<a href=\"" + url + "\">"+ url + "</a><br>");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `<a></a>` tag like below:

```js
document.write("http://goodsamstorefront.com/goodsamstorefront/GetProof.aspx?id=1<br>");
document.write("<a href='http://goodsamstorefront.com/goodsamstorefront/GetProof.aspx?id=1'>I am a Link</a><br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

document.write as below should work

```
document.write("<a href=http://goodsamstorefront.com/goodsamstorefront/GetProof.aspx?id="+docs[i]+"></a>");
```

or  you can create a elements

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('href',link);
a.innerHTML = text;
```

and append but its a lengthy way way